# Getting wrong date in tLogRow

Tags: etl, talend, talend-mdm

In tLogRow1(after trestclient) i am getting correct date. But after tXmlMap i am getting wrong date.

tLogRow1 output =>

`<Date>2020-08-21</Date>`

but in tLogRow2 output =>

```
0027-02-10
```

for that in txmlmap of date expression i wrote `TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd",TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd",[row4.body:/root/root/Date]))`
but still result is same.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By changing date format of Tree Schema Editor of tXmlMap i am able to solve it.